# Add an Icon to a QAction in toolbar

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, cmake

I'm working with Qt in visual studio. I want to add **Icons** in the **menuBar** of my application. Here is what I have so far :

```
QToolBar *View3DToolBar;
QAction * XYZviewAct;
XYZviewAct = new QAction(tr("3D view"), this);
XYZviewAct->setIcon(QIcon("3dicon.png"));
View3DToolBar->addAction(XYZviewAct);
```

The menu bar is shown but it doesn't display the **Icon**.

Has anyone done this using Qt/C++? Could anyone point me to a solution?

Comment: Are you putting the PNG file on the project folder? Because if you not use Qt resource to embed the image in your application, the image must reside on the application executable folder.

Comment: I'm generating my solution with cmake. I added the PNG file to the **.qrc** file and i added the **.qrc** in my **CMakeLists.txt** file, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you are using QToolbar. But basically you can add icon to any action like that

```
newAction->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/new.png"));
```

Note that image is in resources of the application.